# How to use Materialize with RequireJs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, materialize, amd

So far there's no AMD version of [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) which makes it impossible to use with [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/)

I tried using Shim config on RequireJs but I always get an error:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/resources/scripts',
    catchError: true,
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        'materialize': '../../build/bower_components/materialize/dist/js/materialize',
        'velocity': '../../build/bower_components/materialize/js/velocity.min',
        'hammerjs': '../../build/bower_components/materialize/js/hammer.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'materialize': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'hammerjs', 'velocity'],
            exports: 'Materialize'
        },
        'velocity': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

**The error:**

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ()
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Materialize has a lot of problem with requiere. Here share the solution that I found. It works for me in Magento 2:

1. Load this "version" of materialize: https://github.com/ccloli/materialize/tree/AMD-fix/dist/js (note that is not a official release)
2. `var config = {
   paths: {
       'jquery': '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min',
       'materialize': 'Magento_Theme/js/materialize',
       'velocity': 'Magento_Theme/js/velocity',
       'hammerjs': 'Magento_Theme/js/hammerjs',
   },

   shim: {
       'velocity': {
           deps: ['jquery']
       },
       'hammerjs': {
           deps: ['jquery']
       },
       'materialize': {
           deps: ['jquery', 'velocity', 'hammerjs']
       }
   }
   };`

Hope it helps.